# Angular Undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to do some unit testing using Karma and Jasmine.

I followed a tutorial and I when I run karma start I get this error:

> PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) Testing Complaint UI Module Testing
>   Search Page Controller should initialize the itemsPerPage FAILED
>           ReferenceError: Can't find variable: inject in unit/test.js (line 9)
>           unit/test.js:9:29
>            PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR   {
>       "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nTypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'angular.module('ngAnimateMock',
>   ['ng'])\n  .info({ angularVersion: '1.7.2' })')",
>       "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nTypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'angular.module('ngAnimateMock',
>   ['ng'])\n  .info({ angularVersion: '1.7.2' })')"   } PhantomJS 2.1.1
>   (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.003 secs /
>   0.002 secs)

I think the first error (`Can't find variable: inject` is caused by the error in angular-mock.js

My Files in karma.config

```
    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
    'angular.js',
    '../components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    '../app/app.js',
    'unit/*.js'
],
```

Folder Configuration

In Root: app,components,test

Inside test is the `angular.js` and `karma.conf`

Inside components there's `angular-mocks` folder

Inside App there's the app.js file

**What am I missing here??**

Comment: I'm using Angular 1.4.12

Comment: provide the content of your test. Where're you using inject?